# Parse through string in TCL script

Tags: string, tcl

I need to parse through the array and find out a value at particular place in a TCL script

E.g.,
I have a string

> set var "00 01 02 03"

I need to parse through the var to find what is there in the 3rd entry (02).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a TCL [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/list.htm). Remember the index counter starts at 0, so pass in 2 to **lindex** to find the 3rd element

```
% set my_list [list 00 01 02 03]
00 01 02 03
% lindex $my_list 2
02
```

Answer (score 4):

Your string can be interpreted as a list, so you could use `lindex` to get the 3rd list element (counted starting with index 0):

```
lindex $var 2
```

Better would be (and works with different delimiters, too):

```
lindex [split $var " "] 2
```

Comment: Sometimes, it is easier to use `regexp -inline -all` to do the word identification step.